# ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 change only blank selected cells in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, merge, select-by-attribute, null

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2. Is it possible to change only the null values cell in a selected dataset? I could have export the selected features as a new shapefile. Select the null values and replace the blanks. Then merge the shapefile with the original data. Is there an easier option?

[image]

Comment: Shapefiles don't support the concept of nulls. You need to convert to geodatabase (file or enterprise) first.

Comment: Although you talk about exporting to a shape file, you don't state the format of the original data.  Since different data types can handle certain data types differently, e.g., the lack of NULL with shape files, stating the data format is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, to select the records that have empty values, you can make a selection on the attribute with SQL like this -- FieldName = ''. This should give you all the empty fields in your shape file, which is different than null.

Then to replace the empty strings with values you could either:

1. Enter the values manually if the values are different for each cell, by editing them in the attribute view of the shape file under the selection (which will be a highlighted tab in a pale neon blue),
2. Or you could click on the selection that was created (again the highlighted tab in a pale neon blue) and then right-click an empty field that you want to fill. A menu pops up, on the menu go to 'column', and then to 'calculate field'. On 'calculate field' you select the field name under "Fields" so that the dropdown containing "Insert Values" is enabled. Under "Insert Values" you will see 'yourfieldname ='. In the text box below 'yourfieldname =' enter in 'yourvalue'.

**NOTE:** Make sure at the top of the 'Calculate Field' dialog box that you are only affecting the count that what returned by your selection query. I.e. under Input Table, there should be an information message in blue that reads "The Input has a selection. Records to be processed: (number of selection)."

Comment: I found out how to select the null. ArcGISpro 3.1.2 allows to select data in the selected data. I just clicked on select by attribute and added another selection using the AND rather than OR.